# Syncing messages between iPad and iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad

My messages on my iPad won’t sync to my phone. I have tried all of the suggestions. My messages are listed as top conversations in my iCloud storage on iPad. They will not sync. Is there a way to download these to my phone

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We don't know what you tried already or what iOS version you're on.  Do you have Messages turned in `Settings -> <your name> -> iCloud` for both your iPhone and your iPad?  Are they both signed in with the same Apple ID?  How long have you waiting for the messages to sync?

Comment: I have iPhone 7 and the latest update. I have tried everything, checked to make sure I have the same Apple ID. Turning everything off and on. It says it’s downloading but I had it for 12 hours and still hadn’t downloaded